# Filtering a 4D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working with point cloud data that is in the form of a 4D numpy array.  The data is a list of XYZ coordinates and I am trying to find a built-in numpy function to filter out points whose Z-value is greater than some threshold.

This can be easily implemented just using Python but it is painfully slow and requires a new array:

```
#xyz_arr is a list of points in the form [x, y, z]
xyz_filtered = []
for point in xyz_arr:
    if point[2] > threshold:
        xyz_filtered.append(point)
```

I attempted to use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) but was not able to figure out how to look at only one value in the array.

Is there a simpler, more numpy-ish way of doing this?

Comment: I think that what you describe is not a 4D array, but a 2D array of shape ``[n_points, 3]``. Am I misinterpreting you?

Comment: You don't seem to be clear on the difference between an array and a list. Lists and NumPy arrays are entirely different data types; some NumPy functions will automatically convert lists to arrays as a convenience feature, but the types still have crucial behavior and performance differences, and you shouldn't mix them up. If you're working with NumPy, you should almost always be using NumPy arrays rather than lists.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct, I suppose 4D was not the correct way to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Boolean masking](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
import numpy as np

xyz_arr = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
threshold = 3.5

xyz_arr = np.asarray(xyz_arr)

xyz_filtered = xyz_arr[xyz_arr[:, 2] > threshold]

print(xyz_filtered)
# [[2 3 4]
#  [3 4 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.  Guess I need to brush up on my python lists/arrays!